# $p$-Sylow subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb{F}_{p^k})$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, linear-groups

Is there a way to classify all $p$-Sylow subgroups of $GL(n,\, \mathbb{F}_{p^k})$ where $|\mathbb{F}_{p^k}|=p^k$? Clearly the prime $p$ (that is the characteristic of the base field) is a very privileged number; for example we can say that a $p$-Sylow of $GL(n,\, \mathbb{F}_{p^k})$ has order $p^{k(1+2+\ldots+(n-1))}$. But what about the structure of these $p$-Sylows can we identify them as normalizers/centralizers of flags in the projective geometry?

Answer (score 4):

The upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries $1$ form a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$. So the set of all $p$-Sylow subgroup is given by all the conjugates of $P$.

EDIT:
In the light of the answer of Andreas Caranti, $P$ is contained in the stabilizer of the flag $$\{0\} < \langle e_n\rangle < \langle e_{n-1}, e_n\rangle < \ldots < \langle e_2, e_3,\ldots, e_n\rangle < \mathbb{F}_{p^k}^n,$$
where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th standard vector.

EDIT 2, thanks to the comment of Jyrki Lahtonen:
The full stabilizer is still a bit larger than $P$. It is the set of all invertible upper triangular matrices.

Comment: Won't all the upper triangular matrices stabilize this flag? Irrespective of whether they have ones on the diagonal or not? IOW aren't the Borel subgroups the stabilizers of maximal flags.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for pointing this out. Your are right.

Comment: My problem is that the above (complete) flag is not a flag of the projective geometry associated to the vector space $V$ because it contains $\{0\}$ and $V$. The elements of $PG(V)$ are only proper nonzero subspaces.

Comment: This doesn't change anything. $\{0\}$ and $V$ are stabilized by any invertible linear map. So you can safely drop them.